# I would like to plot (stacked bars) top 20 genus/family/species etc. from a phyloseq object?

Tags: r

I have been trying to plot a bar plot on a phyloseq object, agglomerated by species and filtered (so n of ITUs = 542), but for only those top 20 genus that have the highest relative abundance. I want also to do the same for species, orders, etc.

My code to create a classic ggplot barplot for all my taxa (not top 20)

this one for plotting kingdom

```
bar_King<- plot_bar(M.std_Species_filtered, fill="Kingdom", x = 'Type') + 
  geom_bar(aes(color = Kingdom, fill = Kingdom), stat="identity", position="stack") +
  labs(x = "", y = "Relative Abundance\n")  + ggtitle('A')
```

this one for plotting phylum

```
Bar_Phy<- plot_bar(M.std_Species_filtered, fill="Phylum", x = 'Type') + 
  geom_bar(aes(color = Phylum, fill = Phylum), stat="identity", position="stack") +
  labs(x = "", y = "Relative Abundance\n")  + ggtitle('B')
```

Could you please provide a code to plot only top 20 phylum or genus ? probably best is via phyloseq (which I think do not have this function within the bar_plot function).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have created the Fantaxtic package for exactly this purpose. To identify the top n taxa at a taxonomic rank, run the code below:

```r
require("fantaxtic")
require("ggnested")
require("phyloseq")
data(GlobalPatterns)
top_asv <- top_taxa(GlobalPatterns, n_taxa = 10)
```

The `top_asv$ps_obj` is a phyloseq object of the top n taxa at the specified rank, with all other taxa collapsed to `Other`. You can use this object in the regular `phyloseq::plot_bar` function.

A plot with a large number of taxa (e.g. >8) can become difficult to interpret. I therefore also created the `plot_nested_bar` function, which uses colours to show a high-level taxonomic rank, and shades to indicate a lower-level taxonomic rank that is nested within the high-level taxonomic rank. To plot the example above, run:

```r
plot_nested_bar(ps_obj = top_asv$ps_obj,
                top_level = "Phylum",
                nested_level = "Species")
```

[image]

Check out the documentation and more examples on [the Fantaxtic github page](https://github.com/gmteunisse/fantaxtic).